# PHP: Sort Array without changing STARTING key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Is it possible to sort an array without changing the **STARTING** key? If so, how?

I have an array that starts with key 1 (I need it to start with key 1) but as expected, when I sort the array, the starting key becomes 0.

Example code below:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    1 => 'string1',
    2 => 'string2',
    3 => 'string3',
);

print_r($array); //Outputs 'Array ( [1] => string1 [2] => string2 [3] => string3 )'

sort($array); 

print_r($array); //Outputs 'Array ( [0] => string1 [1] => string2 [2] => string3 )'
?>
```

So with this example, I need `$array` to start with key `[1]` after `sort()`.

`asort()` is not an option, as I need the array to be in numerical order (again, starting from 1).

Could anyone help?

Comment: how about after sorting the array do a foreach and create a new array that the key starts on 1.

Comment: On what basis you want to sort

Comment: Instead of sort you need `ksort`

Comment: You can check this:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php, http://www.geekgumbo.com/2011/07/22/php-sorting-and-renumbering-array-keys/

Answer (score 0):

use uasort.
refer following link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php